# Problem styling a Joomla UI accordion on Joomla 2.5 page

Tags: joomla-2.5, jquery

I've successfully installed a jquery ui accordion on a joomla 2.5 page. Using Chrome development tools I can style it but these settings are lost on page reset. Checking out the jquery-ui.css file shows it comes from a CDN  "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css".   jQuery and jQuery UI were installed using the Joomla Easy Query extension. The versions are jQuery 1.10.2 and UI 1.10   I want to have the jQuery UI css file accessible from the server so any css settings are preserved. How can this be done? Thanks

Comment: You're loading an older version of jquery to what is ahipped with Joomla. You can also tell jQuery Easy to load UI locally if need be. But either way, you should NOT edit thr actual UI file. Create a separate CSS file and apply your changes there

Comment: Thank you for your help. OK, I create a new CSS file but which selectors are put in there? Do I copy over the contents of the jquery-ui.css?

Comment: No, not the whole file. You need to add the selectors you want to style.

Comment: I added jquery-ui.css file but I find that in order to get the css to work I have to add !important to the various declarations to get them to work. This is obviously not a good thing. I'm really at a loss about what is happening here

Comment: We can continue this in chat if you wish: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14071/joomla

Comment: Yes, that would be great  I'm living in Thailand time zone UTC+07:00. I would like to implement the UI accordion. I've tried various CSS accordion but I would prefer one that is jQuery based.